# PHP form send to specific email by Select option

Tags: php, forms, email

The contact form I am currently working on sends to 3 email addresses. I would like to have the form send to another email address only when the Naples location option is selected. The other locations do not currently need a separate email address. I tried adding in

`switch($_POST['location'])`

```
{
case “naples″: $my_email = ‘naples@email.com’; break;
}
```

I thought this had worked but no email was sent out when submitted and I couldn't distinguish an error. Is it possible to allow one location option when selected to tack on another email address to the original 3 recipients? Thank you guys in advance code posted below.

```
<?
ob_start();

if(isset($_POST['registersubmit']))
{
    unset($badcaptcha);
    require_once('captcha.php');   
    $privatekey = "....";    
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);   
    if (!$resp->is_valid)
    {
        $badcaptcha=true;
    }
    else
    {
//Send email
//foo@alpha.com
    $to = "foo@alpha.com\r\n";
    $from = "foo@alpha.com <foo@alpha.com>";
    $subject = "Contact Foo\r\n";
    $body = "Contact Foo\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Full Name: ".$_POST['Fname']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Business Name: ".$_POST['Bname']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Email: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Address: ".$_POST['address']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "City: ".$_POST['city']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "State: ".$_POST['state']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Zip Code: ".$_POST['zipcode']."\r\n\n";   
    $body .= "Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Location: ".$_POST['location']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Interests: \r\n\n";
    $body .= "*".$_POST['services1']."*".$_POST['services2']."*".$_POST['services3']."*".$_POST['services4']."*".$_POST['services5']."*".$_POST['services6']."*".$_POST['services7']."*".$_POST['services8']."*".$_POST['services9']."\r\n\n";
    $body .= "Comments/Message: ".$_POST['details']."\r\n\n";   

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: ".$from."\r\n".$headers);

//Send copy  beta@foo.com
    $to = "beta@foo.com\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: ".$from."\r\n".$headers);

    $to = "tom@foo.com\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: ".$from."\r\n".$headers);

    header("Location:thankyou_contact2.php");
    }
}

$linkname="contact";
if(empty($id)) { $id = 10; $showplus = "Y"; }
include("includes/header.php");
?>
 <div id="main"><table width="621" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

   <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
<br />
Use Our Online Form (below) or Contact Your Nearest Location 

<?
if(isset($badcaptcha))
{
?>
     <b><font color="red">INCORRECT SECURITY CODE, PLEASE TRY AGAIN</font></b><br />&nbsp;<br />
<?
}
?>
<br />
            <br />
<div id="contact_form"> <!--onsubmit="return validate2()" -->
<form method="post" name="contact_form" onsubmit="return validate3()" >
<label>
<span>Full Name<font color="#FF0000">*</font></span>
<input size="31" name="Fname" value="<? if(!empty($_POST['Fname'])) { echo $_POST['Fname']; } else { echo "Full Name"; } ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="100" OnFocus="if (this.value == 'Full Name') {this.value=&#39;&#39;}" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value='Full Name'}"/>
</label>
<label>
<span>Business Name<font color="#FF0000">*</font></span>
<input size="31" name="Bname" value="<? if(!empty($_POST['Bname'])) { echo $_POST['Bname']; } else { echo "Business Name"; } ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="100" OnFocus="if (this.value == 'Business Name') {this.value=&#39;&#39;}" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value='Business Name'}"/>
</label>
<label>
<span>Email Address<font color="#FF0000">*</font></span>
<input size="31" name="email" value="<? if(!empty($_POST['email'])) { echo $_POST['email']; } else { echo "Email Address"; } ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="100" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email Address') {this.value=&#39;&#39;}" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value='Email Address'}" />
</label>
<label>
<span>Address</span>
<input size="31" name="address" value="<? if(!empty($_POST['address'])) { echo $_POST['address']; } else { echo "Address"; } ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="100" OnFocus="if (this.value == 'Address') {this.value=&#39;&#39;}" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value='Address'}" />
</label>
<label>
<span>City</span>
<input size="31" name="city" value="<? if(!empty($_POST['city'])) { echo $_POST['city']; } else { echo "City"; } ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="100" OnFocus="if (this.value == 'City') {this.value=&#39;&#39;}" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value='City'}" />
</label>
<label> <span>State</span><select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="State">State</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    </select> </label>
<label>
<span>Zip Code</span>
<input size="31" name="zipcode" value="<? if(!empty($_POST['zipcode'])) { echo $_POST['zipcode']; } else { echo "Zip Code"; } ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="10" OnFocus="if (this.value == 'Zip Code') {this.value=&#39;&#39;}" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value='Zip Code'}" />
</label>
<label>
<span>Phone<font color="#FF0000">*</font></span>
<input size="31" name="phone" value="<? if(!empty($_POST['phone'])) { echo $_POST['phone']; } else { echo "Phone"; } ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="30" OnFocus="if (this.value == 'Phone') {this.value=&#39;&#39;}" onblur="if (this.value == &#39;&#39;) {this.value='Phone'}" />
</label>
<label> <span>Location<font color="#FF0000">*</font></span> <select name="location" id="location">
    <option value="location">Nearest Location</option>
    <option value="Naples">Naples</option>
    <option value="Cherokee">Cherokee</option>
    </select> </label>

 <label>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<strong>Interests</strong> <br />  
<input type="checkbox" name="services1" value="Trucks Sales"<? if($_POST['services1']=="Trucks Sales") { echo " checked"; } ?> />  Trucks Sales 
<input type="checkbox" name="services2" value="Rentals &amp; Leasing"<? if($_POST['services2']=="Rentals &amp; Leasing") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> Rentals &amp; Leasing
</label>
<!-- <label>
<span>&nbsp;</span>           
<input type="checkbox" name="services2" value="Rentals &amp; Leasing"< ? if($_POST['services2']=="Rentals &amp; Leasing") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> Rentals &amp; Leasing
</label> -->
 <label>
<span>&nbsp;</span>           
<input type="checkbox" name="services3" value="Parts"<? if($_POST['services3']=="Parts") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> Parts
<input type="checkbox" name="services4" value="Service &amp; Repair"<? if($_POST['services4']=="Service &amp; Repair") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> Service &amp; Repair
</label>
<!-- <label>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="services4" value="Service &amp; Repair"< ? if($_POST['services4']=="Service &amp; Repair") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> Service &amp; Repair
</label> -->
 <label>
<span>&nbsp;</span>           
<input type="checkbox" name="services5" value="Fleet Maintenance Management"<? if($_POST['services5']=="Fleet Maintenance Management") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> Fleet Maintenance Management&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="services6" value="Other"<? if($_POST['services6']=="Other") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> Other
</label>
<!-- <label>
<span>&nbsp;</span>           
<input type="checkbox" name="services6" value="Other"< ? if($_POST['services6']=="Other") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> Other
</label> -->
 <label>
<span>&nbsp;</span> 
          <strong>Message/Comments</strong>
           <br />  
           <textarea cols="80" rows="8" name="details"><? echo $_POST['details']; ?></textarea></label>
  <label>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
  <script type="text/javascript">  
        var RecaptchaOptions = {     theme : 'clean'  };  
        </script>           
     <?php           
     require_once('captch.php');           
     $publickey = "..."; // you got this from the signup page           
     echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);        
     ?>
 </label>   
      <label>
<span>&nbsp;</span> 
           <input type="submit" name="registersubmit" value="Submit" /></label>
            </form></div>     
<? includecontent($id); ?>                 
</td>
<!-- new --></tr>
               </table>
              </td>
             </tr>   
             <tr>
              <td width="581" align="right" valign="top" colspan="2"><img src="pictures/spacer.gif" border="0" width="10" height="10"></td>
             </tr>
            </table>
           </td>
                     </tr>
         </table><br />
        <img src="pictures/spacer.gif" border="0" width="3" height="3" /></td>
       </tr>
      </table>   
     </div><!-- main -->         
    </div><!-- content -->         
<?
include("includes/footer.php");

?>
```

Comment: a switch() to handle a single case? Why not `if ($_POST['location'] == 'naples') { ... }` instead?

Comment: maybe i didn't understand your problem, are you sure mail() function work for you?, it's better to use SMTP instead of pure mail function, also you can write a function or class for sending mail and call it multi times!

Comment: I am a noob when working with php. Where would the 'if ($_POST['location'] == 'naples') { "naples@foo.com" }' be placed in the code if you don't mind adding more information. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the `$to` variable, not `$my_email`.